# Multi threading requests.post using uWSGI, Pyramid

Tags: multithreading, python-requests, pyramid, uwsgi

I'm trying to request API in multi threading by cron job. I look like to stop or to laze the thread requesting.
It's no problem by `pserve`. I want to use `uWSGI` but I have some problem.

Python 3.5.2

My code is like this:

```
import threading
import requests

def worker(settings):
    lookup_url = settings['lookup_url']
    api_sid = settings['api_sid']
    auth_token = settings['auth_token']
    args = settings['args']
    resp = requests.post(lookup_url,
                         auth=(api_sid, auth_token),
                         data={'data': args},
                         timeout=5.0,
                         )

def main(request):
    registry = request.registry
    settings = registry.settings
    for _ in range(3):
        threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(settings,)).start()
```

Please let me know any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWSGI does not enable Python threads by default:

> By default the Python plugin does not initialize the GIL. This means
>   your app-generated threads will not run. If you need threads, remember
>   to enable them with enable-threads. Running uWSGI in multithreading
>   mode (with the threads options) will automatically enable threading
>   support. This “strange” default behaviour is for performance reasons,
>   no shame in that.

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html

Comment: Thank you so much.
I tried this, It seems good enough.
>>>
[uwsgi]
enable-threads = true